# Swift: How to use "didSelectItemAtIndexPath" in UITableViewController(contains UICollectionView)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, segue

I have a `UITableViewController`, inside the `TableViewCell`, it's a `UICollectionView`. I want to pass the data from the `CollectionViewCell` to a `DetailViewController` when user tapped the cell. I dragged a segue from the `CollectionViewCell` to the `DetailViewController`, and used the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` inside the `TableViewCell`( which contains `CollectionView`), and it works.

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

var posts1: [Posts] = [Posts]()
var posts2: [Posts] = [Posts]()
var categories: [Category] = [Category]()
var selectedPost1: Posts?

@IBOutlet weak var theCollectionView: UICollectionView!


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts1.count

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let collectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        let imageUrlString: String = posts1[indexPath.row].postThumbnailUrlString
        let imageUrl: NSURL = NSURL(string: imageUrlString)!
    //Give Images A round cornor

    let filter = AspectScaledToFillSizeWithRoundedCornersFilter(
        size: collectionViewCell.postImageView.frame.size,
        radius: 20.0
    )

    collectionViewCell.postImageView.af_setImageWithURL(imageUrl, filter: filter)

    collectionViewCell.postTitleLabel.text = posts1[indexPath.row].postTite
return collectionViewCell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("selected")
    self.selectedPost1 = self.posts1[indexPath.row]
}
```

it can print *"selected"* which means the data have already been stored in `self.selectedPost1`. But I can't use `prepareForSegue` inside this class, since it can only be used in `ViewController`. someone told me to implement `UICollectionViewDelegate` in my `HomeTableViewController`, and call the function `didSelectedItemAtIndexPath` in the `HomeTableViewController`, like this:

```
import UIKit

class HomePageTableViewController: UITableViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate {
    let sections: NSArray = ["latest news", "good news"]
    var posts1: [Posts] = [Posts]()
    var selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
  if section < sections.count{
        return sections[section] as? String
    }

    return nil

}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 1
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0 {
        let tableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableViewCell") as! TableViewCell

        tableViewCell.getCategories()
     //   tableViewCell.scrollToNextCell()
     //   tableViewCell.startTimer()


        return tableViewCell

    }
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToDetail", sender: TableViewCell())
    print("selected")
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let tableViewCell1 = sender as? TableViewCell,
    let postDetailPage = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewController{

        let selectedPosts = tableViewCell1.selectedPost1

        postDetailPage.selectedPost?.selectedPost1 = selectedPosts

}
```

However, the `didSelectedItemAtIndexPath` can't be called, there is no print. I don't know why?

here is my `DetailViewController`:

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var postImageView: UIImageView!

var posts: [Posts] = [Posts]()
var selectedPost: TableViewCell?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let post = selectedPost?.selectedPost1{
        let thumbnailUrlString = post.postThumbnailUrlString
        let imageUrl: NSURL = NSURL(string: thumbnailUrlString)!
        print(thumbnailUrlString)
        postImageView.af_setImageWithURL(imageUrl)
    }
}
```

and also do I need to implement in `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`?

I have been struggled in this problem for few days? need some suggestions on How to do Segue from a `UICollectionViewCell` (which is inside a `UITableViewCell`) to a new `UIViewController`.

Comment: for the collectionview inside the didSelectRowAtIndexPath, remove the segue and update me if it does print the "selected"

Comment: I removed the Segue, and it still can print "selected" after I tapped on the cell

Comment: I suggest you to refer [this github code](https://github.com/DipenPanchasara/UITableViewWithHorizontalScroll) which has same implementation which you need. Though in your code you need to set `UICollectionView` delegate inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` using `cell.objectOfCollectionview`.

Comment: ok, I will have a look, @DipenPanchasara. cause I am new to swift, there is still a lot of things don't understand..

Comment: it's written in objective-c, and I am not very familiar with that, I started learning IOS development with swift.@DipenPanchasara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are going is correct, but you are creating one mistake.Try to implement `UICollectionViewDelegate` method `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` also inside `TableViewCell` and remove it from the `HomePageTableViewController`.

Now declare one protocol, after that create its instance inside `TableViewCell` and implement the protocol in the `HomePageTableViewController`, after that in the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` use that delegate instance to call the method like this.

```
protocol PostDelegate {
    func selectedPost(post: Posts)
}
```

Now create its instance inside `TableViewCell` and call this delegate method in the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`.

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
     var posts1: [Posts] = [Posts]()
     var posts2: [Posts] = [Posts]()
     var categories: [Category] = [Category]()
     var selectedPost1: Posts?  
     var postDelegate: PostDelegate?

     func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
         postDelegate?. selectedPost(self.posts1[indexPath.row])
     }
}
```

Now implement this `PostDelegate` protocol inside `HomePageTableViewController`

```
class HomePageTableViewController: UITableViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate { 


     //Your code 

     func selectedPost(post: Posts) {
         //You will get your post object here, do what you want now
     }
}
```

**Note:** Inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` don't forgot to set the delegate of `postDelgate` with your `HomePageTableViewController` like this

```
tableViewCell.postDelegate = self
```

**Edit:**

```
func selectedPost(post: Posts) {
    //You will get your post object here, do what you want now
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToDetail", sender: post)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let post = sender as! Posts
    let postDetailPage = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewController
    postDetailPage.passPost = post
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am new to Swift, not very familiar with create new protocol. so do you mean I need to implement "protocol PostDelegate" inside my TableViewCell? and after that, I put this protocol inside my HomePageTableViewController? I have removed the "didSelectedItemAtIndexPath" from the HomePageTableViewController, do I still need the "func prepareForSegue" in this HomePageTableViewController"?

Comment: Declare protocol out side the `TableViewCell` not inside, create instance of that protocol inside `TableViewCell` like my answer.

Comment: You can declare that `protocol` above the class of `TableViewCell`.

Comment: I already implemented the protocol as you said. and now in the HomePageTableView, what should I do? do I need the prepareForSegue? and inside the `func selectedPost(post: Posts){}`, what should I put? thanks

Comment: In storyboard if you have connected the segue with `tablecell` then remove that and create one between two viewController instead of Tabelcell and viewController. After that call `performSegue` inside that selectedPost method.

Comment: I connected the segue from the HomePageTableViewController to the DetailViewController. and when I tapped on the cell, it didn't work. here is my code in Git [link](https://github.com/guozian/mypracticeapp.git), maybe you can help me have a look. but I am sure if you can run it, cause I download data from my localhost, maybe you can help me have a look at other code. just download the "AppYourBusiness.zip" file. thanks so much

Comment: updated: I forgotten to add `postDelegate` in the HomePageTableViewController, now when I tap on the cell, it perform to segue. the next thing is how to populate data to the DetailViewController? thanks

Comment: That was i am saying you are doing wrong about segue.

Comment: Remove segue that is connected with your collectionViewCell, And create one that connect from `HomePageTableViewController` to `DetailViewController`.

Comment: yes, I have add the segue between `HomePageTableViewController` and `DetailViewController`, and now it's working, but how to populate data from the cell to the `DetailViewController`? thanks

Comment: The project you have given me is have segue connected with cell?, is this old one.

Comment: oh yes, that one is the old one, now I have changed the segue as you told me. but still no image showing when it goes to the `DetailViewController`. thanks

Comment: Can  you give me the project with new one because this one also not have protocol that i have told you to create,

Comment: I have uploaded a new one named" AppYourBusiness2.zip", please have a look, thanks. @NDoc

Comment: Check my answer after **Edit:**, it will solve your problem. Also create on `passPost` object of type `Post` inside `DetailViewController` and use that to download image. like this `var passPost: Posts = Posts()`

Comment: thanks, in my `DetailViewController`, I need to use `passPost` or `selectedPost` as source? cause if I still use the same code in the `viewDidLoad`, it gave me the error "Could not cast value of type 'AppYourBusiness.HomePageTableViewController' (0x10f49a860) to 'AppYourBusiness.Posts' (0x10f49a530)." thanks so much

Comment: No, now you need to use `passPost` object type of `Posts` and get the the image from that `URL`.

Comment: ok, now I did `override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let imageUrlString = passPost.postThumbnailUrlString
        let imageUrl = NSURL(string: imageUrlString)
        postImageView.af_setImageWithURL(imageUrl!)}` but still got the same error. thanks

Comment: You are passing self in the sender you need to pass post object like this `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToDetail", sender: post)`, check edited answer properly you get idea than.

Comment: yeah, sorry. I forgot to change that. it works!! thanks so much!!! you really save my day!!!

Comment: there is another question I don't know if you can help me. in my code, I have a second cell `TableViewCell2`, and content in that cell will automatically scroll every 2 seconds, but when it scrolls to the last one, it will jump to the first one backward, do you know how to make it keep scrolling, like an infinite scroll? maybe I can open another question so that you can Help me? thanks so much!

Comment: I haven't try infinity scroll, but you can check `cocoa controls`, there may you found some library for infinite scroll.

Comment: sorry for asking too much questions. as you can see I have another `TableViewCell2`, I want to do the same thing when user tap the cell inside `TableViewCell2`, I implemented all the same thing, but it gave me an error that "Type TableViewCell2 does not conform to protocol PostDelegat" what should I do to solve this? thanks

Comment: ok, I will try that. thanks. and please help me to have a look on the problems above. thanks

Comment: The problem is you are implementing `PostDelegat` inside the `TableViewCell2`, you need to create the object of the `PostDelegat` and implement the `PostDelegat` where you want data same like `HomeViewController`.

Comment: haha. sorry, I found something wrong I did, now it's working properly. thanks so much!!! Hope you have a good day~~

Comment: Welcome, it is batter if you add another question for your infinite scrolling that will give your batter answer because i don't have try so don't know, if i found something about that, i will inform you and also you too have a great day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121513/discussion-between-leo-guo-and-ndoc).

Answer (score 0):

So, You have not implemented the

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
...
}
```

and

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

methods in your second implementation.
Also, try putting an invisible button over the collection view cell and assign the tag to be the indexpath of that collectionview cell like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell  
{
....
myButton.tag = indexpath.item
}
```

After this you may either implement a delegate callback from collectionviewcell class to the homepagetableviewcontroller class or push the detail view controller directly by code.

As far as setting of image in the detail view controller is concerned. You can do it both in viewdidLoad() or viewDidAppear(). Its fine.

Comment: So you mean I have to implement "numberOfItemInSection" and "cellForItemAtIndexPath" at the HomeTableViewController? Why I need do that? And how many number do I need to return? And for the cell how do I implement it? Sorry I am new to Swift.

Comment: Its not about swift, but in general, a "cellForItemAtIndexPath" is called for each "numberOfItemInSection".
So, If the number of item in section is 0 (or not mentioned). Cell is not formed. And consequently, "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" will not have any effect.

Comment: But in my HomeTableViewController, I have numberOfRowAtIndexPath and cellForRowAtIndexPath. But if I use didSelectedRowAtIndexPath, it didnt work as well. Why is that? Thanks