# UICollectionView in UITableview - Get tag of tapped UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have added `UICollectionView` in `UITableView`. Now, I want to identify on which cell the user taps and the indexPath of that `UICollectionView`.

I'm getting correct `indexPath` but could not get the tag of on which the UICollectionView he tapped. I'm doing something like this to get tap

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("\(collectionView.tag) ---- \(indexPath.item) ")
}
```

**Whole Code**

```
class UserLibraryViewController: UIViewController {

extension UserLibraryViewController : UITableViewDelegate { }

extension UserLibraryViewController : UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return myBooksGenre[section]
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return myBooksGenre.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("userBooksTableViewCell") as! UserLibraryTableViewCell
    return cell
}
}
```

**TableViewCell**

```
class UserLibraryTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
}

extension UserLibraryTableViewCell : UICollectionViewDataSource {

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 12
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("userBooksCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UserLibraryCollectionViewCell



    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    print("\(collectionView.tag) ---- \(indexPath.item) ")


}
}

extension UserLibraryTableViewCell : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let itemsPerRow:CGFloat = 4
    let hardCodedPadding:CGFloat = 5
    let itemWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width / itemsPerRow) - hardCodedPadding
    let itemHeight = collectionView.bounds.height - (2 * hardCodedPadding)
    return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having multiple section in your `tableView`, so you can create one `NSIndexPath` instance in your `UserLibraryTableViewCell` and initialize it in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like this.

```
class UserLibraryTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var tableIndexPath: NSIndexPath?

}
```

Now set this `tableIndexPath` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("userBooksTableViewCell") as! UserLibraryTableViewCell
    cell.tableIndexPath = indexPath
    return cell
}
```

Now in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` of `collectionView` access `tableIndexPath` like this.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

     print("\(self.tableIndexPath) ---- \(indexPath.item) ")
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate :) Have great day :)

Comment: Any idea how to perform segue when user taps on it ? AFAIK I cannot use perform segue in UITableViewCell as segue's under UIViewController. Any way to do this  ?

Comment: For that you need to create custom delegate and implement that delegate in yourViewController, and create its object inside your tableCell, and set the delegate inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`method, for more understanding check this answer of my it will do the same http://stackoverflow.com/a/39031190/6433023

Comment: @Nitesh Check my answer on above comment link i am sure you this will solved your problem.

Comment: Checked that. Didn't helped/understood in my scenario.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39369420/perfomsegues-in-uitableviewcell-class

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("userBooksTableViewCell") as! UserLibraryTableViewCell
    cell.collectionView.tag = indexpath.row
    return cell
}


func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myBooksGenre.count
}
```

You are not setting the `Tag` for the Collection View for the particular cell in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` of Table View.

Update the code.

Also conform `UICollectionViewDelegate` protocol:

```
extension UserLibraryTableViewCell : UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate
```

Comment: `print("\(collectionView.tag) ---- \(indexPath.item) ")` line is executing?

Comment: Yes,  because 0 mean you are selecting, 0th cell of the tableView. Also `numberOfRowsInSection ` and `numberOfRowsInSection ` are misplaced I think. check the update code.

Comment: On all cell's it was showing "0". Anyways thanks a lot for help. Answer provided by NSDoc solved my problem.

Comment: Are you supposed to use multiple sections?

Comment: No. Only one selection at time.

Comment: I meant 'SECTION' not 'SELECTION' :-)

Comment: Yes Multiple SECTIONS