# PerfomSegue's in UITableViewCell Class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uistoryboardsegue

I have `TableView` and inside `TableViewCell` I have added `UICollectionView`. Now when user taps on any `UICollectionView`, I want to pass the data to next `viewController` but unfortunately I cannot use perform segue  inside UITableViewCell class where I have didselect item. Is there any way to perform segue over here ?

**Whole Code**

```
class UserLibraryViewController: UIViewController {

extension UserLibraryViewController : UITableViewDelegate { }

extension UserLibraryViewController : UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return myBooksGenre[section]
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return myBooksGenre.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("userBooksTableViewCell") as! UserLibraryTableViewCell
    cell.tableIndexPath = indexPath

    return cell
}
}
```

**TableViewCell**

```
class UserLibraryTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
var tableIndexPath: NSIndexPath?

}

extension UserLibraryTableViewCell : UICollectionViewDataSource {

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 12
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("userBooksCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UserLibraryCollectionViewCell



    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    print("\(self.tableIndexPath!.section) ---- \(indexPath.item) \(tableSectionHeader[self.tableIndexPath!.section]) ")


}
}

extension UserLibraryTableViewCell : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let itemsPerRow:CGFloat = 4
    let hardCodedPadding:CGFloat = 5
    let itemWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width / itemsPerRow) - hardCodedPadding
    let itemHeight = collectionView.bounds.height - (2 * hardCodedPadding)
    return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one protocol, after that create its instance inside `TableViewCell` and implement the protocol in the `UserLibraryViewController`, after that in the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` of `CollectionView` use that delegate instance to call the method like this.

```
protocol CustomCollectionDelegate {
    func selectedCollectionCell(indexPath: NSIndexPath)
}

class UserLibraryTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var tableIndexPath: NSIndexPath?
    var delegate: CustomCollectionDelegate?
}
```

Now call this method inside your `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` of `CollectionView`.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    print("\(self.tableIndexPath!.section) ---- \(indexPath.item) \(tableSectionHeader[self.tableIndexPath!.section]) ")
    self.delegate?.selectedCollectionCell(indexPath)
}
```

Now implement this protocol in `UserLibraryViewController` like this and set delegate in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("userBooksTableViewCell") as! UserLibraryTableViewCell
    cell.tableIndexPath = indexPath
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
} 

extension UserLibraryViewController : CustomCollectionDelegate {
    func selectedCollectionCell(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Identifier", sender: indexPath)
    }
}
```

**Note:** I have added protocol method with `NSIndexPath` as parameter you can change it with your custom object or with `Dictionary/Array`.

Comment: Not woking. Extension is not getting called. Tried putting a breakpoint.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to set the delegate with self, check the edited answer of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working now as per my requirement. :)

Comment: Hi @NSDoc, i'm having trouble in passing different numberOfItemsInSection. I know normally how to pass different numberOfItemsInSection over here? To all sections same items count is getting passed instead of different.

Comment: Please add new post with new code also with protocol that you have created and where you are getting issue. You have more than one section in table right. so are facing problem in table section?

Comment: Please check this. I'm doing it in these way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39388122/uicollectionview-in-uitableviewcell-sets-tags-to-uicollectionview