# UICollectionView inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I want to implement a function in my viewcontroller that contains a `UITableView` and the `TableViewCell` contains a `CollectionView`,

I want to initiate a function with the selected `CollectionViewCell` that the user press on , but I can't figure out how to distinguish what cell The user selected ,

Right now I use for my `prepareForSegue` :

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.identifier {
    case "SelectedDish"?:
        let myVC = segue.destination as! SelectedDishViewController
          if let indexPath = my_table_view.indexPathForSelectedRow . // this will tell me what cell in the table view the user chose a collectionViewcell
          {
 // here I want to get the index of the collectionViewCell inside the tableview.

    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Is there any different way achieve this?

Comment: Maybe this will help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39362240/uicollectionview-in-uitableview-get-tag-of-tapped-uicollectionview

Comment: Keep one property called IndexPath in your CollectionViewCell, assign value to it from cellForItem(at indexPath:...) like cell.indexPath = indexPath. By using this indexPath of clicked cell, you can easily achieve things.

Comment: I already set a tag for each cell that equals to the indexPath I want to segue to another viewController and pass some data from the specific cell the user tapped on. I’m not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve my issue,

I'm hiding a button in each cell in my collecitonview , each cell has a secition number which is the tableview cell indexpath.row and I assign a index for each collectionview cell where I set each cell , when the button is pressed I store the section and index of the collection view cell and then I use it in prepare for segue.