# UIcollectionview Custom Cell class to didselectitem at

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

my collectionview contains multiple custom cell class that created programmatically. Fun part is I will have a cell that contains another collectionview inside of it. So how to click into this collectionview to present a new view controller? Below are my sample codes on how to create the cell.

```
class MainView: UIViewController {
** main view to display UIcollectionview **
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: userCellIdent, for: indexPath) as! UserContainerViewCell
            cell.Users = users * to display users array*
            return cell

}


class UserContainerViewCell: UICollectionViewCell{
* the uicollectionview that inside a cell , also contains extension to UIcollectioview datasource and delegate to display the cells within this cell*

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: ident, for: indexPath) as! userCell
        let user = featureUsers![indexPath.row]
        cell.config(withUser: user)

        return cell
    }
}



class userCell: UICollectionViewCell {

func config(withUser: UserProfile) { }
** cell class to display the info from the user array **
}
```

So with this setup, how to click into the cell and present a new controller with the User info in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a delegate or hit notification  to viewController on didSelect of internal collectionViewCell and in that method you can present new view controller .

check out the link

[Swift: How to use "didSelectItemAtIndexPath" in UITableViewController(contains UICollectionView)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030309/swift-how-to-use-didselectitematindexpath-in-uitableviewcontrollercontains-u)

Comment: bro any sample code or guide? Because I am very new to swift

Comment: I have edited it .This will tell you how to pass a delegate .You have to do it two way .1st pass delegate to upper cell class and then to vc. Hope   you succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
class UserContainerViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
  var myInstance: MainView!
}

class MainView: UIViewController {
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: userCellIdent, for: indexPath) as! UserContainerViewCell

     cell.myInstance = self

  }

}
```

then inside `didSelectItemAtRow`

```
let vc = myInstance.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "infoView") as! InfoController 

vc.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true;

vc.definesPresentationContext = true;

vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext

myInstance.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: hi, i dont think i want to present the Mainview. I want to present a new view that I can display the user info i pass into.